# Perl Moose: Attribute only getting set when mentioned in BUILD subroutine

Tags: perl, moose

I've building a script that recursively builds the names of a directory's subdirectories/files and the names of the files in those subdirectories as objects:

```
package Dir;
use Moose;
use Modern::Perl;
use File;
use strict;
use warnings;

has 'path' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1); 
has 'name' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', lazy => 1, default => sub { my $self = shift; my ($name) = $self->path =~ /\/([^\/]*)$/; return $name; } );
has 'subdirs' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'ArrayRef[Dir]' );  
has 'files' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'ArrayRef[File]' );  
has 'num_dirs' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', lazy => 1, default => sub { my $self = shift; scalar @{$self->subdirs}; } );


sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;
  my $path = $self->path;

  # run some tests
  logf('Path to the directory does not exist.')             if (!-e $path);
  logf('The path should point to a directory, not a file.') if (!-d $path);

  # populate subdirs attribute with Dir objects
  opendir my $dh, $path or die "Can't opendir '$path': $!";

  # Get files and dirs and separate them out into categories
  my @dirs_and_files = grep { ! m{^\.$|^\.\.$} } readdir $dh;
  closedir $dh or die "Can't closedir '$path': $!";
  my @subdir_names        = grep { -d "$path/$_" } grep { !m{^\.}  } @dirs_and_files;
  my @file_names          = grep { -f "$path/$_" } grep { !m{^\.}  } @dirs_and_files;

  # Create objects
  my @dir_objects =          map { Dir->new  ( path => $path . '/' . $_ ) } @subdir_names;
  my @file_objects =         map { File->new ( path => $path . '/' . $_ ) } @file_names;

  # Populate this with file and directory objects
  $self->subdirs             ( \@dir_objects );
  $self->files               ( \@file_objects );
}

1;
```

Notice the code has a `files` attribute which holds an array of `File` objects. A `File` has the following attributes:

```
has 'path' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1); 
has 'name' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', lazy => 1, default => sub { my $self = shift; my ($name) = $self->path =~ /\/([^\/]*)$/; return $name; } );
```

The problem is that the `name` attribute never gets set when a `File` object is created. I'm not sure why.

**EDIT 1: Solution (sort of)**
So, I slapped this into the `File` object to see if it triggered the creation of the attribute:

```
sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;
}
```

This did not solve the problem. However, this did:

```
sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->name;
}
```

The question I have, though, is why did I need to do this?

Comment: strict and warnings are redundant with Modern::Perl and Moose.

Comment: FYI, You incorrectly claim a path doesn't exist if you have no permission to its parent dir. Also, you incorrectly claim a path to a directory isn't one if you have no permission to its parent dir.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your pattern is failing if there's a trailing slash.

```
my ($name) = $self->path =~ /\/([^\/]*)$/;
```

If `$self->path` is `/some/thing` it works. If it's `/some/thing/` it "works" but `[^\/]*` happily matches an empty string. So you get no warning.

You can put in an optional slash, and change it to match ONE or more non-slashes. Also by using alternative delimiters we can clean up all those leaning toothpicks.

```
my ($name) = $self->path =~ m{/ ([^/]+) /? $}x;
```

But really one shouldn't be parsing paths with regular expressions. Use one of the many built in modules like [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) or [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec)

```
return basename($self->path);
```

---

Some side notes.

Moose is very slow to start up and is best suited for long running processes like web servers. For something as generic as a File and Dir class, consider using [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo). It's mostly compatible with Moose, much faster, and when used in conjunction with [Types::Standard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Types::Standard), does types better. It would be good, for example, to make a StrNotEmpty type to avoid this sort of problem.

Unless this is an exercise, Perl already has a great module to do this sort of thing. Look into [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yeah, this is all pretty much an exercise. Trying to learn the ropes, for the most part. But please see my edit to my original post. Something else is going on that I can't explain.

Comment: @StevieD When you say "triggered the creation of the attribute" how are you checking whether the attribute exists? With `$obj->name` or with `$obj->{name}`? The former is good, the latter is bad. Because the attribute is lazy, it won't exist inside the object until the accessor is used. This is a good lesson in why you don't rely on peeking inside objects.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes with `lazy => 1` are only created when their accessor is called, not after construction.

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note:

You incorrectly claim a path doesn't exist if you have no permission to its parent dir. Also, you incorrectly claim a path to a directory isn't one if you have no permission to its parent dir.

You also needlessly `stat` the file twice. In fact, you needn't `stat` the file at all since `opendir` is already making the checks you are making.

Simply replace

```
logf('Path to the directory does not exist.')             if (!-e $path);
logf('The path should point to a directory, not a file.') if (!-d $path);

opendir my $dh, $path or die "Can't opendir '$path': $!";
```

with

```
opendir(my $dh, $path)
   or do {
      logf("Can't open directory \"$path\": $!");
      die("Can't open directory \"$path\": $!");
   };
```

This also avoids the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in your code, the possibility that the state of things might change between the checks and the `opendir`.

Comment: I agree. This avoids a common problem called a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where you check if an action can be taken and then take an action. Things can change between the check and the action. It's better to just take the action and check if it succeeds.