# Extending a Moose class to enable use of different classes internally

Tags: perl, moose

I'm fairly new to Moose and OO programming. Looking for some guidance. I've got the following `Dir` Moose class that builds a listing of `File` objects:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
package Dir;
use Moose;
use Modern::Perl;

has 'files' =>            (is => 'rw', isa => 'HashRef[File]' ); 

<..>

sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;

<..>

 map { $files{$_} = File->new ( path => $path . '/' . $_ ) } @file_names;
 $self->files ( \%files );

<..>
}
```

I'm trying to write a new class called `MyDir` that `extends` the `Dir` class above. However, instead of creating `File` class objects, I want to use specialized objects that extends `File` objects:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
package MyDir;
use Moose;
use Modern::Perl;

has 'type' =>  (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => '');
has 'files' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'HashRef[MyFile]' );
```

I'm thinking Moose probably has way to do this without rewriting the `BUILD` subroutine but I'm unsure of how to implement this.

Comment: Don't use `map` in void context. That's just a `for` loop.

Comment: Where do `$path` and `@file_names` come from?

Comment: `$path` is an argument passed to the constructor. `@file_names` is just an array of file names inside the directory. I've removed all code not pertinent to the question.

Comment: You've removed too much. I don't understand what your class is supposed to do.

Comment: You can see more of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035292/perl-moose-attribute-only-getting-set-when-mentioned-in-build-subroutine/42035678 This code is slighly older, though.

Comment: Why don't you put the initialization code for `files` into a `builder` method? Then you could override it in a subclass.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.

Comment: `has 'files' => (is => 'ro', lazy => 1, builder => '_build_files'); sub _build_files { ... return { map +($_ => File->new ( path => $path . '/' . $_ )), @file_names }; }` and then a subclass can define its own `sub _build_files`.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `+` in front of the parentheses doing?

Comment: Semantically nothing, but syntactically it separates `map` from the `(` that would otherwise be interpreted as the beginning of a function call, but I want it to be part of the argument. Similar to `print (2 + 3) * 4` (prints 5, multiplies print's return value by 4) vs. `print +(2 + 3) * 4` (prints 20).

Comment: OK, your suggestion was too much work. I found a different route by adding a new attribute: `has 'file_class' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'ClassName', default => 'File');` And now my code that sets the `files` attribute is this: `map { $files{$_}        = $self->file_class->new ( path => $path . '/' . $_ ) } @file_names;`

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution by adding a new attribute:

```
has 'file_class' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'ClassName', default => 'File');
```

And now my code that sets the `files` attribute is this:

```
map { $files{$_} = $self->file_class->new ( path => $path . '/' . $_ ) } @file_names;
```

Comment: I guess this was downvoted because you still use the `map` in a weird way. The approach with the class is fine. It's very extendable. But you should really get rid of that `map` and just do `$files{$_} = $self->file_class->new( ... ) for @file_names;`. It's more readable and it's not using a function that returns a value in void context.

Comment: I'm crushed. Not sure how I can go on with life now.